# Email confirm opening through javascript in outlook, thunderbird etc

Tags: javascript, forms, email, submit

Can you get a email to submit a form as the email is opened, using javascript or whatever language?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `code` <html>
<body onLoad="document.checkfrm.submit();" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<form name="checkfrm" action="www.path.to.my.check.script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="invnumber" value="1423">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="company" value="rest">
<input type="hidden" name="person" value="test">
</form>
</body>
</html>`code`

Comment: sorry I don't know how to add the code in properly

Comment: The main thing that submits the form document.checkfrm.submit()